# How to filter django models data by Date and id using Django Restframwork?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, rest, django-rest-framework

> I am Using Django Rest Frame Work and I Want to build filter time by date and id

**urls.py**

`path('health-heartrate/',healthHeartRate,name='health-heart-rate')`

**Time Field in Database :   2016-03-29 00:00:05.000000**

**views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def  healthHeartRate(request):
    if request.method=='GET':

        strDate=request.query_params.get('strDate',None)
        strDate=datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

        endDate=strDate + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
        filter_date=Health.objects.filter(pk=id).filter(time_gte=strtDate).filter(time_lte=endDate)

        serializer=HealthFilterSerializer(filter_date,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

`Url > http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/health-heartrate/?id=1&strDate=2016-03-28`

**I got the Following Error in Browser**

```
TypeError at /api/v1/health-heartrate/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` refers to the builtin [**`id`** function [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). You need ot obtain this parameter, for example with:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def  healthHeartRate(request):
    pk = request.query_params.get('id')
    str_data = request.query_params.get('strDate')
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

    end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    filter_date = Health.objects.filter(
        pk=pk,
        time__gte=start_date,
        time__lte=end_date
    )
    serializer=HealthFilterSerializer(filter_date,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

The lookups can be accessed with a *double* underscore, so `__gte`, not `_gte`.

Comment: @VishaSingh: yes, you can do that. Note however that you will need to repwrite the `time_gte=...` and `time_lte=...` filters to `time__gte=...` and `time__lte=...`

Comment: didn't you mean `pk = request.query_params.get('id')`

Comment: @VishalSingh: yes, the point is that you need to obtain the `id` from the querystring.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it return empty list

Comment: @Haseeb: well that is perfectly possible, for example if the `Health` object with `id=1` was not generated on `2016-03-28`.

Comment: @VishalSingh Yes pk = request.query_params.get('id')

Comment: @Haseeb: you say that the time field in the database is `2016-03-29`, shouldn't you then query with: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/health-heartrate/?id=1&strDate=2016-03-29`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sir  Time Field in Database : 2016-03-29 00:00:05.000000,How i can query thanks for your time

Comment: @Haseeb: see comment above. But the id is not per se 1. Note that furthermore this will return exactly one, or no record, since the id of each record is unique.

Comment: @Haseeb: hold on, your `time` is a `TextField`? You should make it a `DateTimeField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I will change it lets see

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your view into a much simpler version as,

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def healthHeartRate(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        date_input = request.query_params.get('strDate', None)
        pk = request.query_params.get('id')
        health_qs = Health.objects.filter(pk=pk, time__date=date_input)
        serializer = HealthFilterSerializer(health_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Unsupported lookup 'date' for TextField or join on the field not permitted.Kindly Help

Comment: seems like your `time` is a `TextField` rather than a `DateTimeField`